# VBA Script Code for reading a xls and manipulating cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with just one worksheet. The first row of this excel sheet has the Title for the columns.

The worksheet has data in below columns and n number of rows:

Columns: A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H

1. First I am creating a copy of the file and renaming it - This WORKS!

   ```
   'Copy and rename the file
   Dim sourceFile As String, destFile As String
   sourcePath = Range("D6")
   destFile = Split(sourcePath, ".")(0) + "_Formated.xls"
   FileCopy sourcePath, destFile
   ```
2. I want to read this destFile excel sheet via VBA code. I will doing some cell manipulation so please give me a working code to understand how that whole worksheet is read and how I can access a particular row while in a for loop.
3. I also want to know the code to add new column title and values to this destFile excel sheet via VBA code.
4. Whats the code for just clearing the cell value via VBA code and not delete the cell.

Comment: regarding 4. - use `Range("A1").ClearContents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this done with the below code. 
This is the worst way to code it and does not look anything sophisticated but it gets the job done.
Thanks!

```
Sub Format()

'Copy and rename the file
Dim SourceFile As String, DestFile As String
SourceFile = Range("D6")
SourceString = Range("D3")
TestSuiteName = Range("D2") & "\"
DestFile = Split(SourceFile, ".")(0) + "_Formated.xls"
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fs.FileExists(DestFile) Then
    FileCopy SourceFile, DestFile
End If

'Read DestFile worksheet content
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Workbooks.Open(DestFile).Worksheets(1)

Dim rowRange As Range
Dim colRange As Range
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = wks.Cells(wks.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Step 1" Then
        Cells(i, 7) = "Other_Migration_Fields" & Cells(i, 7) & vbLf & vbLf & "QC Path:" & Cells(i, 8)
        Cells(i, 8) = Replace(Cells(i, 8), SourceString, TestSuiteName)
    Else
        Cells(i, 1) = ""
        Cells(i, 2) = ""
        Cells(i, 7) = ""
        Cells(i, 8) = ""
    End If
Next i

ErrorHandler:
    Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    Else
        MsgBox "Success!"
    End If
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> 2. I want to read this destFile excel sheet via VBA code. I will doing some cell manipulation so please give me a working code to understand how that whole worksheet is read and how I can access a particular row while in a for loop.

```
dim sh as Worksheet
set sh =  Workbooks.Open(destFile).Worksheets(1)
```

> 3. I also want to know the code to add new column title and values to this destFile excel sheet via VBA code.

```
sh.rows(1).Insert Shift := xlDown
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).Copy sh.Rows(1)
```

> 4. Whats the code for just clearing the cell value via VBA code and not delete the cell.

```
sh.Range("A1").Value = ""
```